# How can I creature error bars with matplotlib when I use the .group method when setting my x in ax.bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I am making a graph with 4 subplot (2x2). 
My data is currently arranged in long form like:

```
group score

1       2
1       3
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       4
2       5
2       1
3       2
3       1
3       6
3       4
```

What I want is for each bar to have an error bar representing the standard error of the mean.

I've tried putting the values in for yerr but every time I do I get an error that it they arrays don't match in size, which I believe is due to me using df.group for my x value. Should I be doing something else to denote my x and y? The bar charts are what I want them to look like at this point, I just can't get the error bars to work. What should I be using instead?

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=False, sharey=True, figsize=(15,7))
ax1.bar(df.group, df["score"], yerr = [?,?])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use the group column. You want to use [`GroupBy()` followed by `aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) to calculate the values that you want in each group.

```
d="""group   score

1       2
1       3
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       4
2       5
2       1
3       2
3       1
3       6
3       4"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\\s+')
gr = df.groupby('group')['score'].aggregate(['mean','sem'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=gr.index, height=gr['mean'], yerr=gr['sem'], capsize=10)
ax.set_xticks(gr.index)
```

[image]